# Lotus Notes automation - how to get data from System.Net.Mime.HeaderCollection - UIPATH, VBA

Tags: .net, lotus-notes, lotus, uipath

I’m looking for help - hot to extract data from System.Net.Mime.HeaderCollection
it contains structure like this:

```
{
“message”: “System.Net.Mime.HeaderCollection”,
“level”: “Information”,
“logType”: “User”,
“timeStamp”: “16:43:03”,
“processVersion”: “1.0.0”,
“jobId”: “2a144551-9ab6-4c36-8e21-408a26399d894”,
“robotName”: “AuditFord”,
“machineId”: 213229
}
```

I tried to get it by assign activity like:
var = mail.Headers(“Date”) but it return null
also
mail.Headers("“timeStamp”:") does not work
I found this https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.Mime.html but UiPath does not recognize it for IBM Notes.

My goal is to get the date when the email has come to email and if someone marked it as read

Here is my workflow:

[image]

Also:

[image]

Comment: sorry by null I meant 2nd screen - a collection

Comment: Vague question, to me at least, very vague. Why scrape a screen if there are several APIs available to interact with Notes/Domino in a more appropriate way? And is this really a Notes question??

Comment: Hi, so I have to work with Uipath I only found IBM activities in it - if you know any of API for UIPath env could you write me a name of it?

Comment: Maybe you could put your problem on the UIPath forum? https://forum.uipath.com/search?q=lotus

Comment: I did it, but no know has answered my post

Comment: It's sad but I'm afraid I cannot help you either, for I know nothing about UIPath at all. I can only suggest that you read other questions on that forum to see if there's one that more or less fits your problem. So sorry...